# Is two web servers and one shared file server a good idea?

Tags: network-share, synchronization, architecture, infrastructure, shared-storage

Current problem:

- we have a single web server that hosts a website with user generated content
- the server constantly needs more upgrades to keep up with the storage space
- it's hard to make changes without temporarily disabling the website

Idea to fix these problems:

- add a file server that is responsible for storing all data (it provides a shared remote directory and a remote MySQL server)
- add two web servers that each access the file server
- one web server will be used as a development environment (with optional access to the production data)
- the other will be used as a production environment
- when the development server works as intended the changes will be added to the production server

All three servers will run their applications as docker containers.

Is this a good idea or are there flaws? I'd be thankful for feedback.

Comment: moreover, it depends on the requirements. sometimes it's a good choice to use a cdn or a cluster or or or... we can't tell you how to do your business we can act on facts that are missing here.

Comment: Ok, stupid question... how is adding a server going to help with "the server constantly needs more upgrades to keep up with the storage space"? You will still require constant upgrades to keep up with the storage space.